# Integral of a continuous 1-form on a sequence of $C^1$ curves

Tags: smooth-manifolds, curves, approximation-theory

Suppose I am given some continuous $1$- form $\omega$ defined on $\mathbb{R}^2$, and a fixed curve $C$ that is the boundary of a bounded open set $\Omega$. Let $\{C_j\}^\infty_{j=1}$ be some sequence of $C^1$ curves.

In what "sense" of convergence of $C_j$ to $C$ would imply that  $\int_{C_j}\omega$ converges to $\int_C \omega$ ?

Given $C$ and $\Omega$ could I always find $C_j$ contained in $\Omega$ that converge to $C$ in this "sense"?

Comment: Putting $\Omega$ aside for a moment, one case to consider would be to think of $C_j$'s as parameterized by functions $\gamma_j$ in $C^1([0,1];\mathbb{R}^2)$; $\lim_{j\to\infty}\gamma_j\to \gamma_\infty$ in uniform $C^1$ topology (which is a natural topology on the function space) would certainly imply convergence of integrals.

Comment: Regarding whether or not one can approximate the boundary of $\Omega$ from within, one needs to be mindful of the obvious obstructions of connectedness and holes.